# flutter iOS&Android deploy from gitlab CI/CD

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gitlab, cicd

I have a gitlab flutter repo, and I use CI/CD too *(with gitlab runner)*. The currently state it's building the iOS and android part well, and can download it as artifacts when finished.

But I need to deploy to android/iOS store, without 3rd party 'paid' services. I read many documentation, but everywhere I read, its needed to implement services like codemagic, apprise, bitwise, etc... which has a limited minutes/credits for free, but the services not free if you out of the free minutes/credits.

So can't do it natively somehow? I mean the builded iOS/Android app deploy to the stores from gitlab pipes?

Comment: Check out https://fastlane.tools/ which is a standard tool for deploying apps and app meta data (screenshots) to the stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/upload) might help you.
In your gitlab pipeline you should be able to upload the apk/aab file using these APIs.

Answer (score -3):

The `gitlab` pipeline doesn't allow you to deploy to stores. However, speaking for iOS, there is a new feature (Still in Beta) called Xcode cloud from which you can specify a certain branch and each time you commit to this branch it will build and release to test flight.

Comment: This is unfortunatelly not correct. It is possible to deploy apps directly from a CI pipeline.